# Trying to run the requests module still won't work despite installing it (via pip3)?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pip, python-requests

Want to keep this short and sweet.

I'm trying to run the requests module, and utilise urllib on Python 3.6.3. I'm on MacOSX 10.12.

I installed Pip3 and ran the pip3 commands, such as "pip3 install requests", which should activate requests, right...?

[Here's my screen when I type "pip3 freeze" if it helps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlXJe.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the error you get when you try to use requests.

Comment: Here: https://imgur.com/a/wBnPY

Comment: The green represents the specific folder I was executing the command from, and the orange is specific parts of the website link. This is a test, where I was trying to extract specific image links from a website using the requests module. It worked in the past, and when I typed a value of numbers for the code to search for (seeing if jpg subdomains existed) it would cycle through them very quickly with no errors (using pip). But a week ago I accidentally deleted some stuff and now it *runs*, but gives a timeout error. Not sure what to make of this.

Comment: One last thing, a sample of the actual code, in download.py: https://imgur.com/a/2i8qN

Answer (score 1):

When you do `import urllib.request` you are not actually importing the `requests` package that you installed, instead you are just using the `request` module of the builtin `urllib` package. You should do `import requests` instead. You can find the `requests` package docs [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Here is some sample code to download a file

```
import requests
url = 'http://example.com/image.png'
r = requests.get(url)
with open("image.png", "wb") as image:
    image.write(r.content)
```

Also your output shows `Operation timed out` as the error, that's usually a network related issue.

---

Since you asked, this is how to write your code sample using requests:

```
import requests

start = int(input("Start range: "))
stop = int(input("End range: "))

for i in range(start, stop+1):
    filename = str(i).rjust(6, '0')+".jpg"
    url = 'https://website.com/Image_' + filename
    print(url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open(filename, "wb") as image:
        image.write(r.content)
```

Comment: What would I substitute these lines with: 
 try: urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e: if I'm using "import requests"?

Comment: Looks like you are just starting out in your programming journey.  I am adding the code you asked. But, I strongly recommend taking your time to understanding the basics of the Python language and programming in general. The changes are very simple and you should know how it works more than what it does.